# В чем причина возврата указателя или мусора из памяти?

Tags: c++, c++11, openssl

`VS 2013`, консольный, `x64`-разрядный проект.

Версия `OpenSSL`: 1.0.2h x64

Метод получения хеша `SHA1`:

```
#include <openssl/sha.h>

void SHA1::ComputeHash(std::vector<unsigned char> &buffer, std::vector<unsigned char> &result)
    {
        int i = 0;
        SHA_CTX sha1handler;
        unsigned char sha1digest[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH] = { 0 };
        auto str = std::string(buffer.begin(), buffer.end());

        SHA1_Init(&sha1handler);
        SHA1_Update(&sha1handler, &str, str.size());
        SHA1_Final(sha1digest, &sha1handler);

        Framework::Array::Copy(sha1digest, 0, result, 0, SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH);
    }
```

Метод `Framework::Array::Copy`:

```
void Array::Copy(unsigned char *sourceArray, int sourceIndex, std::vector<unsigned char> &destinationArray, int destinationIndex, int length)
    {
        if (destinationArray.size() == 0 || destinationArray.size() < (destinationIndex + length))
            destinationArray.resize(destinationIndex + length);

        for (int i = sourceIndex; i < (sourceIndex + length); i++)
        {
            destinationArray[destinationIndex] = sourceArray[i];
            destinationIndex++;
        }
    }
```

Метод `Framework::Array::AddRange`:

```
void Array::AddRange(std::vector<unsigned char> &sourceArray, std::vector<unsigned char> &destinationArray, int offset, int length)
    {
        for (int i = offset; i < (offset + length); i++)
            destinationArray.push_back(sourceArray[i]);
    }
```

Метод, в котором возвращается указатель или мусор из памяти вместо значения:

```
void Hash(std::vector<unsigned char> &inData, std::vector<unsigned char> &salt1, std::vector<unsigned char> &salt2, int salt)
{
    std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(20);
    std::vector<unsigned char> buffer2(4);
    std::vector<unsigned char> destinationArray(0x30);
    int num = 0;
    for (num = 0; num < 3; num++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++)
            buffer2[i] = (salt + num);
        std::vector<unsigned char> localBuffer;
        Framework::Array::AddRange(buffer2, localBuffer, 0, (num + 1));
        Framework::Array::AddRange(inData, localBuffer, 0, 0x30);
        Framework::Array::AddRange(salt1, localBuffer, 0, 0x20);
        Framework::Array::AddRange(salt2, localBuffer, 0, 0x20);

        SHA1::ComputeHash(localBuffer, buffer); // Вот тут в buffer возвращается указатель или мусор из памяти!
    }
}
```

Вопрос - почему возвращается указатель\мусор? Если нужны еще какие либо данные - напишите в комментариях.
Не первый раз уже сталкиваюсь с подобным, в прошлый раз не удалось воспроизвести проблему, надеюсь хоть в этот раз причина станет ясна.

---

**Update:**

Удалось выяснить что указатель\мусор возвращается из OpenSSL,
пример смены значения:

1) http://i7.5cm.ru/i/kkXu.png

2) http://i7.5cm.ru/i/caXS.png

Метод:

```
void SHA1::ComputeHash(std::vector<unsigned char> &buffer, std::vector<unsigned char> &result)
{
int i = 0;
SHA_CTX sha1handler;
unsigned char sha1digest[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH] = { 0 };

// Выводим HEX значение буфера
printf("Buffer HEX: ");
for (int i = 0; i < (int)buffer.size(); i++)
    printf("%X-", buffer[i]);
printf("\r\n\r\n");

std::string str = std::string(buffer.begin(), buffer.end());

// Выводим длину строки
printf("Str Length: %u\r\n\r\n", str.size());

// Выводим HEX значение строки
printf("Str HEX: ");
for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
    printf("%X-", str[i]);
printf("\r\n\r\n");

if (!SHA1_Init(&sha1handler))
{
    printf("SHA1_Init == false\r\n"); // Все ок, сообщение не выводится
}
if (!SHA1_Update(&sha1handler, &str, str.size()))
{
    printf("SHA1_Update == false\r\n"); // Все ок, сообщение не выводится
}
if (!SHA1_Final(sha1digest, &sha1handler))
{
    printf("SHA1_Final == false\r\n"); // Все ок, сообщение не выводится
}

// Выводим HEX значение результата обработки SHA1
printf("SHA1 result HEX: ");
for (int i = 0; i < SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
    printf("%X-", sha1digest[i]);
printf("\r\n\r\n");

Framework::Array::Copy(sha1digest, 0, result, 0, SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH);
}
```

p.s. попробовал более старую версию OpenSSL (v1.0.1t x64) - проблема так же сохранилась.

---

**Тестовый проект:** https://www.sendspace.com/file/japr5z

**OpenSSL под Windows:** https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

Comment: Методы Init, Update и Final возвращают в качестве результата булево значение, говорящее о том, корректно ли отработала функция. Что они возвращают у Вас ? Или у Вас они по другому реализованы ?

Comment: @isnullxbh, все отлично, все функции отработали нормально судя по бул значениям, которые они вернули. Но проблема сама осталась. Обновил метод в вопросе.

Comment: Вам не кажется это значение FFFFFFFF - подозрительно большим, при выводе ?

Comment: @isnullxbh, переделал на wstring - FF пропали, сверяю значения.

Comment: @isnullxbh, FF пропали, строка wstring один в один с вектром buffer. Но это не помогло, значение так же динамически меняется( Уже не знаю куда копать....

Comment: а проект закрытый, потестировать нельзя ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44251/discussion-between-isnullxbh-and-alexis).

Comment: @isnullxbh, 15 минут, попробую портировать основное в отдельный проект и вопросизвести проблему.

Comment: @isnullxbh, добавил в вопрос ссылку на тестовый проект.

Comment: Меня вот смущает что все ваши функции - void SomeFunc() и о возвращаемом значении речи идти не может. К тому же, SHA1 работает с байтами, а у меня возникают сильные подозрения относительного того, что вы в алгоритм передаете.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не хватает репутации для комментария.

@Владимир Мартьянов, все правильно он передает:

```
BYTE == unsigned char == [0...255]
```

Другое дело, в какой форме он передает..

Проблема в том, что в `SHA1_Update` передается `std::wstring`, хотя в параметрах она принимает стандартную си-строку. Рекомендации:

1) Заменить `std::wstring` на `std::string`.

2) Заменить `SHA1_Update(&sha1handler, &str, str.size())` на `SHA1_Update(&sha1handler, str.c_str(), str.size())`

p.s. Вам придется еще как то разобраться с `FFFFF`, `wstring` - отсекает их, а `string` - нет.

Comment: А Вы как думаете, если она только отсекает - это не решает проблему ? Не могло ведь  при выводе оказаться такого большого значения ? Если так, то на вход поступили не корректные данные.

Comment: @isnullxbh, функция удаляет\игнорирует неверные данные (в данном случае FFFFF) из std::string, так что результат возвращаеся корректный.

Comment: @Alexis, но откуда там взялись _неверные_ данные ?

Comment: @isnullxbh, вот этого к сожалению не могу сказать, вектор с байтами передается корректный, лишние данные записывает конструктор `std::string str = std::string(buffer.begin(),buffer.end());` Почему - для меня непонятно, судя по данным из интернета - `std::string` не нуль терминированная. Да `0xFF` далеко не `0x00`.